# How to serve Docker containers with Nginx if there are multiple sites on one host?

Tags: nginx, docker

I have three web-apps on one server: two nodejs apps and one php. Now I don’t use containers, so the flow is following:

One Nginx is running. It select backend and static files dir by hostname. E.g. if I go to `mysite.com` it proxy requests to `localhost:3000` and use static files from `/sites/mysite/static`. If I go to `sistersite.com` nginx proxy requests to PHP and use static files from `/sites/sistersite.com` and so on.

Now I want to *isolate* applications and try Docker. Should I include Nginx to each container and resolve hosts-to-container by something to it or should I include only application and use common Nginx installed to the host machine? If second, how to return static files? By adding `root /path/to/static/in/container`? Sites also support both http and https, so they use different certificates.

Answer (score 1):

Either method you described will work. Making an Nginx+Node container and an Nginx+PHP container where each container is the complete self-sufficient site is the cleanest form of isolation. It's easy to see how you could add additional sites, or change your PHP site into a Rails site (or other dramatic rewrite) without anything outside the container being affected. However, you'll need some third (Nginx?) service to route from your host to the containers, so you've added an extra hop to the network.

Alternatively, you could put each site into its own container and have a third container for your (singe instance of) Nginx. You can use [`--volumes-from`](http://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#volume-shared-filesystems) on the Nginx container to mount the static data from your two site containers.